# Unable to access toBlocking() in xctest

Tags: swift, rx-swift, rxtest

I am trying to write test cases and trying to access a method which returns Single object. For this I want to use toBlocking but I am not able to access it and getting following error:

> Value of type 'Single<[Property]>' (aka
>   'PrimitiveSequence>') has no member
>   'toBlocking'

Following is my code

```
 do {
        let property = try viewModel.getPropertyList(city: "1530")
            .toBlocking()
            .single()
        XCTAssertNotNil(property)
    } catch {
        XCTFail("Get user settings failed")
    }
```

Already imported following frameworks:

```
import RxCocoa   
import RxSwift  
import XCTest
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `import RxBlocking` too!
if it raises error then you should add `RxBlocking` to your Test target in your package manager.

For example in `Pod` you should have something like this in your `Pod` file :

```
target 'YourProjectTests' do
    pod 'RxSwift',    '~> 4.0'
    pod 'RxCocoa',    '~> 4.0'
    pod 'RxBlocking', '~> 4.0'
    pod 'RxTest',     '~> 4.0'
end
```